# HTTP GET and POST, how to implement in Angular 2 to be able to list, add and remove objects

Tags: http, typescript, angular

Okay, so I am new to working with HTTP and actually getting some data from the server. Been sifting through a lot of tutorials, examples and questions asked here, but I am not finding what I want. All tutorials I've found only shows how to retrieve and add some data.

So based on those examples I've managed to retrieve data:

service:

```
getCases(){
    return this.http.get('someUrl');
}
```

Case component constructor:

```
this._service.getCases()
        .map((res: Response) => res.json())
        .subscribe(cases => this.cases = cases);
```

Adding cases

service:

```
public saveCase(case: case) {

    let body = JSON.stringify(case);
    let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

    return this.http.post('someUrl', body, options)
        .map(this.extractData)
        .catch(this.handleError)
        .subscribe(case => this.cases.push(case));
}
```

Case Component:

```
saveCase() {
    let case = new Case(this.id, this.name, this.date)    
    this._service.saveCase(case);
    this.name = '';         
}
```

Okay, so I have and Array "Cases" which contains Case objects. Getting the data from the server displays the cases like I want them to. When I add a new case it gets sent to the server, but how do I get the Array updated when I add a new Case. Because now the new case appears only after I refresh the browser.

Second question is that the user can click a case and it then routes to a detail list where the user can add steps and feedback. If it matters, case has the attributes id, name, date and an array of steps, at this point the array is empty. The step object is it's own class and the object contains an array of feedback. Feedback is also an own class and the object has two attributes, which are both strings. So it's all nested. When I click the case, it does route to the detail page, but there the case name should be printed and it doesn't. It also shows my button for adding steps, but it does nothing. Obviously I'm missing something in my methods, but I have no clue to as what to do. As a comment I can say that before adding the http in my code it all worked as it should. Here are the methods, that are probably missing something:

Case Component:

```
gotoDetail(case: Case) {
    this._router.navigate(['CaseDetail', {"id": case.name}]);
}
```

Service:

```
public getById(id: string): Case {
    for (let case of this.cases) {
        if (case.id === id) {
            return case;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Then there is the matter of syntax for removing cases, haven't found an example that works for me yet, I've tried a bunch... among others the example links provided by @shershen below. None works. The original methods I have, that should be changed to work with http:

Component:

```
removeSearchCase(case: Case) {
    this._service.removeCase(case);
}
```

Service:

```
    public removeCase(value: Case): void {

        let index = this.cases.indexOf(value);
        this.cases.splice(index, 1);
}
```

So the case removal is with post.

And about the backend I can say as much that I only have the following three posts and gets:

getCases (GET), saveCase (also works as updating the case)(POST) and removeCase (POST).

Comment: I wonder why you expect the array to be updated. Either you make a `GET` call after the `POST` call to get the latest state from the server or you update the array on the client as well after the `PUT` call succeeds. To the routing issue: What Angular2 version are you using?

Comment: Oh well, of course I need to add the getCases. How did I not think about that?! Yeah, well the list updates now as it should, thanks for pointing that out! As for the routing... I'm using Angualar version beta 17.

Comment: Hard to tell why name is not shown from the information you provided. If you could create a Plunker to reproduce this would be way easier.

Comment: [http://plnkr.co/edit/dtDj7K4Gn3l6yAYQyiyE?p=preview] This is an older version, and it's also missing the "steps", but the issue is with routing, so it shouldn't matter. Some things have changed, like the attributes for the Case... but as I said, it all worked before starting to connect my code to the backend. Inside comments is the code I'm using, just kept the original methods there, so that the app works... Hope this helps???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to debug without sample demo, however the descriptions quite detailed. I am adding some points that may fix the problem while improving the code structure:

- First, you should move the request subscription/observing into the service methods; that will encapsulate the request handling logic in service layer:

```
//service.ts
@Injectable()
export class service {
  getCases(){
    if (!this.request) {
      this.request = this.http.get('/assets/data.json')
        .map((response: Response) => response.json())
        .map((data: string[]) => {
          this.request = null;
          return this.names = data;
        });
    }
    return this.request;
  }
}
```

- Second, you need to create an instance of your service in your Component's constructor instead of using it as a static method of the service:

```
//component.ts
import {MyService} from 'PATH_TO_YOUR_SERVICE';

class CaseComponent {
  constructor(private _service : MyService){
    //other stuff..
  }
  getData(){
    this._service.getCases()
  }
}
```

Additional references:

- [Official "Getting and Saving Data with HTTP"](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt6.html)
- [Service example with Observables](https://coryrylan.com/blog/angular-2-observable-data-services) (with Firebase, but still)
- [Simple service in Angular2 seed project](https://github.com/mgechev/angular2-seed/blob/master/src/client/app/shared/name-list/name-list.service.ts)

Comment: Thanks! I changed it. I actually had in mind to do just like that, but my "boss" suggested I would do it like I did. (I'm doing my work internship).

Answer (score 0):

I think you should put your cases Array in the CaseComponent:

case.component.ts:

```
cases: Case[];
constructor(private caseService: CaseService){}

getCases() {
  this.caseService.getCases()
        .subscribe(cases => this.cases = cases);
}

saveCase() {
  let case = new Case(this.id, this.name, this.date);
  this.caseService.saveCase(case)
        .subscribe(case => this.cases = [...this.cases, case]);
}
```

case.service.ts:

```
getCases() {
    return this.http.get(this.casesUrl)
                     .map(this.extractData)
                     .catch(this.handleError);
}

saveCase (case: Case) {
    let body = JSON.stringify({ case });
    let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

    return this.http.post(this.casesUrl, body, options)
                    .map(this.extractData)
                    .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

Then try to change "name" to "id" in gotoDetail:

```
gotoDetail(case: Case) {
  this._router.navigate(['CaseDetail', {"id": case.id}]);
}
```

Comment: yes sorry, that "name", "id" was a typo! And I did have the cases array in the component as well, just did include the method, thus it doesn't show there in my code! Any help with the remove case method? I've not even gotten an useful try, because everything I've tried just gets underlined errors all the time... I've included my methods in my original question.

Comment: In service return this.http.delete(url, headers).map(this.extractData). Obs: headers = new Headers({'Content-Type':'application/json'}). In component: this.caseService.delete(case).subscribe(case => this.cases = this.cases.filter(c => c.id !== case.id));